# how to add keys symbol & and software center package link in askUbuntu answer?

Tags: discussion, markdown, formatting

I know this very dumb question in Ask Ubuntu.
I want to know how in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115408/how-do-i-change-my-control-or-alt-key-to-emit-a-space-key-event) the key symbols are attached in question 
and in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116494/how-can-i-add-more-wallpapers-in-11-10/116908#116908) (in answer section 2 question) how Ubuntu software center open directly from clicking on link.
I tried in formatting help but not found anything.

Comment: Did you see this [link](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)?

Comment: thanks all of u :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/editing-help will help you out.

Use `<kbd>Your Key Here</kbd>` for <kbd>Your Key Here</kbd>. To link to the Software Center, use `[package name](link)`.